# Yii2.0:generated image cannot be displayed after configuring urlmanager rules

Tags: php, yii2

main.php:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    // 'showScriptName' => true,
    // 'enableStrictParsing' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'metting/<sid:\d+>/<b:\w>'=>'metting/attender/index',
    ],
 ]
```

view page:

```
<img src="<?= Url::to(['ticket/qrcode', 'bank' => urlencode($ticket->linkUrl)])?>">
```

qrcode action:

```
public function actionQrcode ($bank) {
    $level = \dosamigos\qrcode\lib\Enum::QR_ECLEVEL_L;
    $bank = urldecode($bank);
    return \dosamigos\qrcode\QrCode::png($bank,false,$level,4,0);
}
```

when I remove the rules configuration,the image is display normally.

Comment: What is exactly `url` produced of `<?= Url::to(['ticket/qrcode', 'bank' => urlencode($ticket->linkUrl)])?>`?

Comment: generate a qrcode image with php, I find that if I add `ob_clean()` before `return \dosamigos\qrcode\QrCode::png($bank,false,$level,4,0)`,image show normally.But I don't know how configuration rules affected the output buffer

Comment: May be you should add leading slash? `/ticket/qrcode`

Comment: Your url-rule in urlManager is not triggered by that img-url so it seems strange. Do you have some setting in apache/nginx that cause problems?

Comment: By debugging, I found that if the configuration was added, the buffer content would have a space before the output image